# How to combine CNN and fully connected sub-network as side head using keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I would like to implement this architecture in keras:

[RoomNet Encoder-Decoder architecture with fully connected side head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1M3L.png)

The idea is to have raw images as input and output room layout keypoint estimates.

The encoder convolutes the raw images. The encoder output is used by a "side-head" with fully connected layers to output a room class. The decoder upsamples the ecoder output and produces a set of keypoint estimations. The loss function of the model is a combination of the "keypoint loss" and the "room type loss".

This is my implementation so far:

```
    ## encoder ##
    # 1. block
    encoder_input = Input(320, 320, 3)
    conv_layer_1_1 = Conv2D(64, 3, 1, padding='same')(encoder_input)
    batch_norm_1_1 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_1_1)
    relu_1_1 = ReLU(batch_norm_1_1)
    conv_layer_1_2 = Conv2D(64, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_1_1)
    batch_norm_1_2 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_1_2)
    relu_1_2 = ReLU(batch_norm_1_2)
    max_pool_1, indices_1 = MaxPoolWithIndex()(relu_1_2)
    # 2. block
    conv_layer_2_1 = Conv2D(128, 3, 1, padding='same')(max_pool_1)
    batch_norm_2_1 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_2_1)
    relu_2_1 = ReLU(batch_norm_2_1)
    conv_layer_2_2 = Conv2D(128, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_2_1)
    batch_norm_2_2 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_2_2)
    relu_2_2 = ReLU(batch_norm_2_2)
    max_pool_2, indices_2 = MaxPoolWithIndex()(relu_2_2)
    # 3. block
    conv_layer_3_1 = Conv2D(256, 3, 1, padding='same')(max_pool_2)
    batch_norm_3_1 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_3_1)
    relu_3_1 = ReLU(batch_norm_3_1)
    conv_layer_3_2 = Conv2D(256, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_3_1)
    batch_norm_3_2 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_3_2)
    relu_3_2 = ReLU(batch_norm_3_2)
    conv_layer_3_3 = Conv2D(256, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_3_2)
    batch_norm_3_3 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_3_3)
    relu_3_3 = ReLU(batch_norm_3_3)
    max_pool_3, indices_3 = MaxPoolWithIndex()(relu_3_3)
    dropout_3 = Dropout(rate=0.5)(max_pool_3)
    # 4. block
    conv_layer_4_1 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(dropout_3)
    batch_norm_4_1 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_4_1)
    relu_4_1 = ReLU(batch_norm_4_1)
    conv_layer_4_2 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_4_1)
    batch_norm_4_2 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_4_2)
    relu_4_2 = ReLU(batch_norm_4_2)
    conv_layer_4_3 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_4_2)
    batch_norm_4_3 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_4_3)
    relu_4_3 = ReLU(batch_norm_4_3)
    max_pool_4, indices_4 = MaxPoolWithIndex()(relu_4_3)
    dropout_4 = Dropout(rate=0.5)(max_pool_4)
    # 5. block
    conv_layer_5_1 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(dropout_4)
    batch_norm_5_1 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_5_1)
    relu_5_1 = ReLU(batch_norm_5_1)
    conv_layer_5_2 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_5_1)
    batch_norm_5_2 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_5_2)
    relu_5_2 = ReLU(batch_norm_5_2)
    conv_layer_5_3 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_5_2)
    batch_norm_5_3 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_5_3)
    relu_5_3 = ReLU(batch_norm_5_3)
    max_pool_5, indices_5 = MaxPoolWithIndex()(relu_5_3)
    encoder_output = Dropout(rate=0.5)(max_pool_5)

    ## decoder ##
    # 6. block
    upsampling_6 = MaxUnpooling2D([encoder_output, indices_5])
    conv_layer_6_1 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(upsampling_6)
    batch_norm_6_1 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_6_1)
    relu_6_1 = ReLU(batch_norm_6_1)
    conv_layer_6_2 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_6_1)
    batch_norm_6_2 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_6_2)
    relu_6_2 = ReLU(batch_norm_6_2)
    conv_layer_6_3 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_6_2)
    batch_norm_6_3 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_6_3)
    relu_6_3 = ReLU(batch_norm_6_3)
    dropout_6 = Dropout(rate=0.5)(relu_6_3)
    # 7. block
    upsampling_7 = MaxUnpooling2D([dropout_6, indices_4])
    conv_layer_7_1 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(upsampling_7)
    batch_norm_7_1 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_7_1)
    relu_7_1 = ReLU(batch_norm_7_1)
    conv_layer_7_2 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_7_1)
    batch_norm_7_2 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_7_2)
    relu_7_2 = ReLU(batch_norm_7_2)
    conv_layer_7_3 = Conv2D(256, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_7_2)
    batch_norm_7_3 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_7_3)
    relu_7_3 = ReLU(batch_norm_7_3)
    # 8. block -> prediction
    conv_layer_8_1 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_7_3)
    batch_norm_8_1 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_8_1)
    relu_8_1 = ReLU(batch_norm_8_1)
    conv_layer_8_2 = Conv2D(512, 3, 1, padding='same')(relu_8_1)
    batch_norm_8_2 = BatchNormalization(conv_layer_8_2)
    decoder_output = ReLU(batch_norm_8_2)
    self.cnn = Model(encoder_input, decoder_output)

    ## room type learning ##
    input_mlp = Flatten(encoder_output)
    dense_layer_1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(input_mlp)
    dense_layer_2 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(dense_layer_1)
    output_mlp = Dense(512)(dense_layer_2)  
    self.mlp = Model(input_mlp, output_mlp)
```

I am really not sure how to combine the components:

1. Should each component be its own keras model? How would they be combined?
2. Should there only be one model? How would the combined loss be implemented and how would the side head update its weights? How would I manage labels in this scenario, by passing two labels while only having one input (again how would the fully connected weights be updated)?

Comment: From where you have imported MaxpoolWithIndex and MaxUnpooling. In which portion you're having trouble the blue lines named pooling indices or Dense output to type5 layer named Room Type Inference

Comment: The MaxpoolWithIndex and MaxUnpooling functions are from https://github.com/ykamikawa/tf-keras-SegNet. I am having trouble combing the three models to one end-to-end model. The forward pass from encoder input to decoder is simply calling each layer with the output from the layer before. But when it comes to compute the gradient (from both losses from the encoder-decoder output and the fully connected layers) I am not sure how to implement this. Especially regarding the learning of the weights of the fully connected layer. Also, how should I pass the room lables in Model(input, output)?